# Is there a OS-Tool / Plugin for "trailing curve simulation"?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations

A customer was asking me for a "trailing curve simulation" (german: Schleppkurve) on QGIS or OSGIS basis. A interesting question but I found nothing on the internet.

A tailing curve is the space a vehicle like a bus or truck needs to drive a street. The customer have got some heavy trucks up to 80m length (!!) and would like to use QGIS for this tasks. And of course, QGIS could do everything! For now, he is using this german software https://www.rzi.de/aktuelles/nachrichten/nachricht/rzi-schleppkurve/

Comment: The problem in itsels seems to be more a mathematical/geometrical one. Do you have any details about the principles of the solution used in the other software? How is a trailing curve simulated? Without this information, it's difficult to give any advice.

Comment: A short internet research revealed that trailing curves are often used together with CAD software. So probably it would be good to get a few information from there about the principles how to model it. See e.g. here: https://www.schleppkurve.com/ - it would be good to provide more information to focus the question.

Comment: See here a paper about the topic, including some algorithms. One algorithm used seems to be Everling-Schoss (p. 245): Kuczora V. (2015) Schleppkurven. In: Straßenentwurf mit CARD/1. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-658-10051-3_15 and Petrović P. (1967) Die mathematische Darstellung der Schleppkurve. In: Die Kehre im Gebirgsstraßenbau. Springer, Vienna. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7091-7956-7_5

Comment: Here a very similar problem as yours. They used QGIS, but exported it afterwards to DXF/Auto-CAD, so this seems to be an established workflow. Is there a reason why you want to use GIS instead of CAD software? The point is primarily about OS, not necessarily GIS, right? Here the paper: Befahrbarkeit plangleicher Knotenpunkte mit Lang-Lkw, http://www.bast.de/DE/Verkehrstechnik/Fachthemen/v1-lang-lkw/Berichte/890284.pdf